# Smartphone Gyroscope Range (radians / second)

Tags: sensor, android, gyro, gyroscope

I'm using gyroscope recordings of Android Smartphones. The measurements are in radians / second. I recognized that sometimes there are some outliers and also the range is different between smartphones. Thus, currently I'm clipping at -20 and 20 radians / second for each dimension (x,y,z).

I don't know if 20 radians / second for rotation of a smartphone is much or not. Is this a reasonable value or what clipping values should be used?

Comment: reasonable value for what end use?

Comment: @jsotola These are gyroscope measurements during usual daily smartphone usage. I'm using these measurements to analyse smartphone usage and predict activity and other variables (e.g. emotions).

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I don't have a feeling how fast 20 radians/s are, that's why it is difficult to judge if it make sense during daily smartphone usage. What values do you think make sense during daily smartphone usage? My first goal is to remove outliers (e.g. sensor failures).

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat According to the Android documentation Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE is "All values are in radians/second and measure the rate of rotation around the device's local X, Y and Z axis." Please see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent#sensor.type_gyroscope:

Comment: So 20 radians/s means 3.18 rotations of your phone in 1 second.  So 20 radians/s makes absolutely no sense relative to a phone!  So your question cannot be answered as formed because 2π radians = 6.283185 radians = 360°.  That is basic math.  My last comment on this. [How many radians in 360°?](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+radians+in+360+degrees&rlz=1C1CHBD_enCA930CA930&oq=how+many+radians+in+360+degrees&aqs=chrome..69i57j6.12893j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Thanks for the explanation. Do you think that 2pi / s, i.e. 360deg / s are realistic for a smartphone?

Comment: It depends on your purpose and what you're trying to sense, how often you are polling and how you will interpret out of range values.  What is the fastest rotation you'd want to accurately detect?  Do you need to detect when the phone is dropped or when a person flips it in the air?  I assume you're clipping to remove outliers, but the amount of clipping you would need would vary by device. so that may not be the best plan.  Have you tried doing a datalog of spinning a phone as fast as you can to see if the gyroscope maxes out?

Comment: why is everyone focused on spinning the phone? ... see what data values you get if you hold the phone in one hand and run as fast as you can ... or just log a full day's activity